# Подключение блока «Поделиться» от Яндекса

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Доброго времени суток.

Вставляю в код страницы, копируя из API:

```js
<script src="https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<script>
var share = Ya.share2('my-share', {
    content: {
        url: 'https://yandex.com'              
    }
    // здесь вы можете указать и другие параметры
});
</script>
```

```html
<div id="my-share"></div>
```

Но, кнопки не инициализируются. Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так?

Comment: смотрите ошибки в консоли браузера

Answer (score 2):

Всё оказалось совсем просто. Скрипт инициализации запускать после формирования div.

```js
var share = Ya.share2('my-share', {
    content: {
        url: 'https://yandex.com'              
    }
    // здесь вы можете указать и другие параметры
});
```

```html
<script src="https://yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<div id="my-share"></div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, отметьте ответ как принятый.